# How can i short a url in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I installed a php script that using Yii Framework on my Local Xampp Server. How can i change this URL http://localhost/magicweb/home/shop/client-name-1 to  http://localhost/magicweb/client-name-1 ? Is there any easy way to do this with .htaccess or i need to do this using Yii controllers? I am very new to php and yii framework.

Comment: You need to build a set of urls patterns to use throughout your application.  Yii UrlManager has already a patter "controller-name/action-name". If it does not suit you, customizing UrlManager may help. Please let me know if that's not clear enough.

Comment: Where can i find some examples ? Thanks for your help

Comment: you can refer here
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: Thanks again @Klaus but it looks very complicated. It would be great if there where a way to do this using htaccess.

Comment: Yes, I think, but it'll be more complex than using Yii's way. Yii has already a mechanism for it. Could you give more details on what you're trying to achieve. I could get you more direct answer. Are you trying to show client's info using this url:  http://localhost/magicweb/client-name-1. I assume "magicweb" is your web directory. Is it correct.?

Comment: @Klaus Yep. I am trying to setup a business directory. Right Now the url for a shop is http://localhost/magicweb/home/shop/mcDonalds and i want visitors to use this URL http://localhost/magicweb/mcDonalds to display the McDonalds Profile Page. And yes "magicweb" is my web directory. It would be great if you could guide me on how can i achieve this. Once again thanks.

Comment: I've added a new answer. Please let me know if you get stuck in any steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use slug

   - install and follow this extension's direction http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/slug-behavior/

The extension above add a "slug" column in your business vendor table (shop, i assume) and updates the column whenever a record is created or updated. You will use "slug" column as an unique id in the URL to show vendor's info. For example: /mc-donalds, /starbucks or /burger-king.

2. Add an url rule in your UrlManager config in main.php, before the existing rules as follows:

> ```
>  '<slug:[-a-zA-Z]+>' => 'vendor/view',
> ```

The above rule will point to "vendor" controller and "view" action, in the action, you will specify a slug parameter which is got from url, then you will query a "shop" record using this slug and show its info to view.

You would need a slugify function:

```
public static function getSlug($string) 
{

    //remove any '-' from the string they will be used as concatonater
    $str = str_replace('-', ' ', $string);
    $str = self::removeAccent( $string );

    // remove any duplicate white, and ensure all characters are alphanumeric
    $str = preg_replace( array('/\s+/', '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/'), array('-', ''), $str);

    // lowercase and trim
    $str = trim(strtolower($str));
    return $str;
}
```

You will get to vendors' page by localhost/magicweb/mc-donalds, localhost/magicweb/starbucks or localhost/magicweb/burger-king